# Django: Handling several page parameters

Tags: python, django, list, parameters, httprequest

I have several possible parameter to process in a page. Assume x0, x1, x2,..., x1000. It seems awkward to get and process them one by one by request.GET.get('x0'), request.GET.get('x1'), ...

Any idea to put them in a list, so that they can be processed in a loop.

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific. `request.GET` is a dictionary-like object, you can iterate it however you like. What exactly are you doing? Show some code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, just curious for my own understanding...what makes it "dictionary-like" rather than an actual dictionary?

Comment: It's a [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects), which is a custom dict subclass that enables multiple values for a single key - hence the frequent questions we get here about `.get()` vs `.getlist()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But my problem was not to have several amounts for one parameter. The solution is shown below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, `request.GET` is a dictionary, you can access its values like this:

```
for var in request.GET:
    value = request.GET[var]
    # do something with the value ...
```

Or if you want to put the values in a list:

```
val_list = []
for var in request.GET:
    var_list.append(request.GET[var])
```

Comment: Very useful. But every var would be something like x5, x21, etc. Can I separate its index section, to have something like 5, 21, etc in another variable?

Comment: Thank you. The solution was very simple. I used var.replace("x","") to delete x, and then I used casting to convert and put it in an int variable. :)